# iOS 10: Random Crashes in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app under iOS 10, objective-c. The app runs fine from one to several hours until it crashes.

The strange thing is that the crash is always at the beginning of some block dispatch with dispatch_async (__gcd_queue_item_enqueue_hook_block_invoke). The block is never the same.

Tested leaks and varios malloc tests. Memory usage is low. It seems it is not a memory issue. Still nothing.

I am clueless at this point on how to proceed for debugging. Any suggestions welcome.

**Edit:** here is a complete stack trace from the last crash:

```
* thread #254, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x24)
frame #0: 0x00000001006f2e08 libBacktraceRecording.dylib`__gcd_queue_item_enqueue_hook_block_invoke
frame #1: 0x00000001006f238c libBacktraceRecording.dylib`gcd_queue_item_enqueue_hook + 224
frame #2: 0x00000001012e5e48 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_introspection_queue_item_enqueue_hook + 40
frame #3: 0x00000001012c5304 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_push + 196
* frame #4: 0x00000001000e2850 Lucky`-[LuckyViewController onEventsChanged:](self=0x000000010181a200, _cmd="onEventsChanged:", events=@"14 elements") at LuckyViewController.m:1517
frame #5: 0x00000001001f7c2c Lucky`-[TutorManager strategyLoop2](self=0x000000010165e4b0, _cmd="strategyLoop2") at TutorManager.m:723
frame #6: 0x000000018e62f318 Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 996
frame #7: 0x000000018cbfd68c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 240
frame #8: 0x000000018cbfd59c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 284
frame #9: 0x000000018cbfacb4 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?  It might be helpful since the actual issue might be further back than the current statement.

Comment: Thanks, added stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not with `dispatch_async`.

Apple Technical Support confirmed that it's a bug within the `libBacktraceRecording.dylib` library, which is used for debugging within Xcode.

> it won't crash on a users device since this is a debug error that
>   occurs within a library not present on most users' devices.

In short, if you're seeing `libBacktraceRecording.dylib` at the top of your stack trace, it's probably this, and likely not an error in your code